# Testing whether neighbors are more similar to each other than distant points

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spatial, distance, metric

Suppose you have points x1...xn in a metric space X, each is associated with some measurement y1...yn.
I want to test whether points closer to each other in X have similar associated value y.
I have few ideas, but it seems like a familiar question, so there are probably some general theory and test with regard to this, which I'd be happy to hear about.

For example, for graph structures there are some "autocorrelation" measures, or lagged correlation.
Other ideas I had would be to create a data for pairwise distances and pairwise differences in Y and find test for correlation between the two.

Other ideas and references would be much appreciated.

EDIT: why correlating distances with differences may not work (or at least, won't represent what I'm looking for)
When correlating distances (in X) to differences (in y) you expect that low distances will result in low differences, and that high distances will likely go with high differences. While the first part is exactly what I'm looking to test, the second part is not. To say it crudely, I don't care what happens far away. I only care what happens locally near a given point. It is similar to continuity of functions in mathematics.

To account for that, my second thoughts are to look not at pairwise distances, but at balls of varius radii around points, and the variance of those points that are within those balls. my hypothesis is that the higher the radius of the ball, the higher is the variance within the ball (normalized by total variance in the data or something similar)

still not sure if i'm in the right direction here.

Comment: One may define and compute a suitable (that metric space) distance between all the poins. Likewise, define and compute suitable (dis)similarity function between the points based on featute `y`. Then to correlate these two set of values.

Comment: @ttnphns thanks. That was my first shot at this, but it seems overly simplistic, and I think it doesn't really catch the phenomenon exactly.

Comment: see an update for explanation about why correlating distance with differences might not work